# Calculate p-value for a probplot with normal distribution and ci 95% from an pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, p-value

I want to calculate the p-value from an pandas dataframe and add it to the plot. This is my working code except the p-value:

```py
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Hacker-Festzelt': [1.068510948, 1.111444388, 1.097928649, 1.097319892, 1.112046892, 1.096458863, 1.098193952, 1.105528912, 1.081012023, 1.096862587, 1.096820787, 1.112483864, 1.090409846, 1.076176749, 1.05914969, 1.111281072, 1.090280455, 1.071867235, 1.104982445, 1.074247709, 1.103154487, 1.136741808, 1.051554041, 1.089669195, 1.126347645, 1.105658808, 1.117330659, 1.101642591, 1.065208517, 1.082705561, 1.081997508, 1.100248942, 1.102306684, 1.106034801, 1.061078385, 1.065105824, 1.118714312, 1.103743509, 1.10806331, 1.127161842, 1.095313864, 1.083297614, 1.088053678, 1.096490414, 1.103947732, 1.070520785, 1.096987797, 1.045452588, 1.097941923, 1.087059407]
})

# Calculate statistical measures
mean = df['Hacker-Festzelt'].mean()
stdev = df['Hacker-Festzelt'].std()
n = len(df)
result = stats.anderson(df['Hacker-Festzelt'])

# Retrieve critical values
ad_stat = result.statistic
critical_values = result.critical_values

# Get p-value
p_value = result.significance_level[np.where(
    result.statistic < result.critical_values)[0][-1]]

# Fit the data to the normal distribution
params = stats.norm.fit(df['Hacker-Festzelt'])

plt.figure(figsize=[15, 11])  # Set the figure size here

# Create the probability plot
probplot = stats.probplot(df['Hacker-Festzelt'],
                          dist=stats.norm(*params), plot=plt)
regression = np.polyfit(probplot[0][0], probplot[0][1], 1)
se = np.sqrt(np.mean(
    (probplot[0][1] - np.polyval(regression, probplot[0][0])) ** 2))
conf_interval = stats.t.interval(0.95, len(
    probplot[0][1]) - 2, loc=np.polyval(regression, probplot[0][0]), scale=se)

# Scatter plot for data points
plt.scatter(probplot[0][0], probplot[0][1], color='blue', zorder=3)

# Plot confidence intervals for 'Hacker-Festzelt'
plt.fill_between(probplot[0][0], conf_interval[0], conf_interval[1],
                 color='red', alpha=0.2, label='CI (95%)')

# Set y-axis label
plt.ylabel('Ordered Values')

# Set x-axis label
plt.xlabel('Theoretical Quantiles')

plt.grid(zorder=-1)

# Add text annotations
text = f"Mean: {mean}\nStDev: {stdev}\nN: {n}\nAD: {ad_stat}\nP-Value: {p_value:.3f}"

plt.annotate(text, (0, 0), (0, -30), xycoords='axes fraction',
             textcoords='offset points', va='top')

plt.tight_layout()
# Hide x-axis labels
plt.xticks([])

plt.savefig('pp-simple-normal-dist.png')
```

The values `mean`, `stdev` and `AD` are correct. But the p-value should be in this case `0.123` but my output is `1.000`. How to calculate the correct p-value and is this depending on the used distribution like `lognorm`, `gamma`, `norm` etc.

[image]